# Area 51 login is borked with SE openID ("unable to login with your openID provider")

Tags: bug, area-51, login

When I attempt to login to Area 51 with my normal credentials (a Stack Exchange openID) I get this error:

[image]

Comment: What OpenID provider are you trying to use?

Comment: @TheGuywithTheHat It's in the title (SE openID). I'll edit to make it a bit more obvious.

Comment: No issues here for me, both my existing login session and a fresh one work fine.  Clear your cache?

Comment: Same problem here. When I created my SE account I used Google to log in and added a SE openID later. On Area 51 I cannot login using my SE openID but have to use the Google login.

Comment: Oh, and this is the same in both Firefox and Chrome. I get an error message similar to the one in the screenshot.